# How to access the return value from a function that has an error handling callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, jwt

I have a function that should return data or throw an error from JSON web token custom function, the data returned from the signer part of the function does not get assigned to the token const instead return undefined I am using typescript

please how do I make the data return from the signer be assigned to my token const

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import ms from 'ms';

const expiresAt = ms(process.env.WEB_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME as string);
const signer = async (payload: string | object | Buffer) => {
  console.log({ expiresAt });
  const jsonSecretToken = process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN as string;
  const token = await jwt.sign(
    payload,
    jsonSecretToken,
    {
      expiresIn: expiresAt,
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw new Error();
      console,log(data) // return "shows a valid token"
      return data;
    }
  );
  console.log({ token }); // return undefined
  return token;
};

const decoder = async (token: string) => {
  const jsonSecretToken = process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN as string;
  const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, jsonSecretToken, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    return data;
  });
  return decoded;
};

const tokenGenerator = Object.freeze({ signer, decoder });

export default tokenGenerator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only way you can access the data is to access it inside the callback. Because the code is async. You can make your function to accept a callback and call it.

Another way to work with async code is to use Promises. You can wrap your function call into a promise and resolve it when you get the data or reject it in case of an error.

Next step is to use async await syntax to work with promises in a way like sync code looks

Comment: The OP is already using `async` and `await`, but is incorrectly also using callbacks

Comment: Yep but OP using it in a wrong way, so my answer leads to a right way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you sign asynchronously you need to provide a callback function as in the example here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

```js
//https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' }, function(err, token) {
  console.log(token);
});
```